# How can I depict $~u\left(r\right)=\frac{1}{r}\exp\left(ir\right)~$?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, exponential-function, wave-equation

I want to depict the graph of the following formula .

$$  u \left( r \right) = \frac{1}{ r }  \exp\left(i r\right)  $$

Needless to say as we depict a locus of $~ \exp\left(i r \right)  ~$ , the circle with radius $~ 1 ~$ can be shown .

As we call $~ \frac{1}{ r }  ~$ as an amplitude , then this amplitude becomes smaller as $~ r ~$  increases .

Hence I thought the graph is like as the below one .

[image]

Is this graph is close to the correct one ?

I even want to depict it using some software .

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E%28ix%29%2Fx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $r$ is only a real number then we can expand the equation, as $e^{ix}=cos(x)+i$ $sin(x)$,

So we get $u(r)= \frac{cos(r)}{r}+i\frac{sin(r)}{r}$, so if we plot the real component we get
[image]

and if we plot the imaginary component.
[image]
(the plots where made using [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator))

hopefully that helps.

Comment: Maybe you are supposed to type $\sin r$ instead of $\sin x$?

Comment: @soupless thanks

Comment: You should say that function $\phi$ defined by $\phi(r)=\dfrac{\sin(r)}{r}$ is called "cardinal sine".

Comment: @JeanMarie that makes sense as to why its sometimes called sinc(r), from "**sin**e **c**ardinal". Also is $\frac{cos(x)}{x}$ called cardinal Cos